# ExtJs 4 MVC Application Architecture: How to reference a file in a subfolder

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm trying to use this structure on a project:

- app > view > MyWindow1.js
- app > view > MyWindow2.js
- app > view > ui > MyWindow1.js
- app > view > ui > MyWindow2.js

However, if I want to insert a subfolder, like:

- app > view > window3 > MyWindow3.js

I don't know how to reference it.

In my app.js, I can reference MyWindow1 and MyWindow2 by:

> var win1 = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyWindow1'); var win2 =
>   Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyWindow2');

But, how can I reference MyWindow3?

I tried

> var win3 = Ext.create('MyApp.view.window3.MyWindow3');

, but no success.

Comment: What are the contents of app/view/window3/MyWindow3.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application `name` is `MyApp` and your `appFolder` is app, then `Ext.create('MyApp.view.window3.MyWindow3');` is correct. Check the define clause and make sure it is all spelled correctly, and also make sure the spelling and capitalization matches in both the define and the folder. IE: `Ext.define('MyApp.view.window3.MyWindow3', //....` The errors for misspellings in either case is very vague, but you will come to recognize it.

Comment: Yep, it will get you every time. I only wish the error messages were more clear.